# Confusing behavior on function scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I am new to javascript and while I was practicing scope I tried the following code:

```
var il = "inner";
var o ="outer";

var of = function(){

  console.log(o + " " + il);

  o = "baher";
  var il = "ander";
  console.log(o + " " + il);

  var lf = function(){
    console.log(o  + " " +il);
    o = "mazed baher";
    var il = "mazed ander";
    console.log(o + " " +il);
  };

  console.log(o + " " +il);

};

of();
console.log(o + " " + il);
```

//////////////////////////////////////
Its output is amazing

```
"outer undefined" 
"baher ander" 
"baher ander" 
"baher inner"
```

I cannot understand this code. I used `console.log` 6 times and only got four outputs. And why is "il" is undefined on the first log?

Comment: Two of your `console.log` inside function that is never called.

Comment: `il` is undefined because of variable hoisting.

Comment: You are confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it only giving output four times

Two of your `console.log` statements are inside the `lf` function, which you never call.

> why "il" giving undefined first time

`var` statements are hoisted.

```
var of = function(){
    console.log(o + " " + il);
    o = "baher";
    var il = "ander";
```

The last line in this section creates a local variable `il` in the scope of the function. Since it is hoisted, this happens as soon as the function is entered.

The second line reads the value of that local variable, but it hasn't been assigned a value yet so it is `undefined`.

The third line then assigns a value to it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, new scope is created only for functions. condition blocks like `while` and `if` do not create new scope.

Secondly, variable definitions in JS will always be lifted on top of scope. So, when you create variable via `var` it will be actually defined on top of scope and initialized as `undefined`.

```
console.log(o + " " + il);
o = "baher";
var il = "ander";
```

In given sample, local `il` will override `il` from outer scope. So, it will look like this:

```
var il; // undefined
console.log(o + " " + il);
o = "baher"; // outer scope
il = "ander"; // inner scope
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The code has `var il = "ander";` inside function block so it's taking but before calling this the code logs it so it's undefined.
2. Same happens in your nested function but before this it's nested function so it's taking the value of ander defined in parent function.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `il` is `undefined`, is that it is re-declared inside the function `of`, and the declaration gets hoisted to the top of the function (but not the assignment). See the code below to see what I mean. I also showed how the other variable declarations get hoisted as well.

The reason two of the log statements aren't run is that the function `lf` is never called.

```
var il = undefined;
var o = undefined;
var of = undefined;

il = "inner";
o ="outer";

of = function(){
    // il gets hoisted
    var il = undefined;
    var lf = undefined;

    console.log(o + " " + il);

    o = "baher";
    il = "ander";
    console.log(o + " " + il);

    // this function is never called
    lf = function(){
        var il = undefined;
        console.log(o  + " " +il);
        o = "mazed baher";
        il = "mazed ander";
        console.log(o + " " +il);
    };

    console.log(o + " " +il);

};

of();
console.log(o + " " + il);
```